# Backbone Marionette and Webpack - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'radio' of undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, backbone.js, marionette, webpack

I recently did an **npm install** on my *webpack/backbone/marionette* project and everything broke. I now keep getting this error when I application runs:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property  'radio' of undefined**

*backbone.marionette.js line 3328*

```
this.channel = _.result(this, 'channel') || Backbone.Wreqr.radio.channel(this.channelName);
```

**Backbone**: 1.2.3 (I also tried the brand new version from today of 1.3.1)

**Marionette**: 2.4.4

**Webpack**: 1.12.14

I thankfully had a backup of my old node_modules and noticed this difference in the marionette library folder structure.

[image]

Any idea what's going on? I hadn't touched my package.json I just re-ran npm install with what it seems like a new version of npm/node.

**UPDATE**
I found this thread where at least one person had the exact same issue but I still don't have a solution
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/2559

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by add a alias in my webpack configure file.

```
alias: {
    backbone: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'backbone', 'backbone')
}
```

I noticed that webpack packs multiple copy of backbone.js in its output file if without alias.

Answer (score 1):

Helped to set deps in `package.json` to:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "backbone.marionette": "^2.4.4",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
```

(removed backbone dep completely)